# What is wrong when Open atrium is installed with no colors and images?

Tags: media, distributions

I have successfully installed Open Atrium. Upon opening the site first time in the browser, i literally see no images, layouts of colors. Here is the screenshot:[image]

I also have a series of warning messages being displayed as shown below:

[image]

Anyone has a clue, what's wrong really?

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible for us to debug your localhost

Comment: @Mołot I did install Drupal successfully on my localhost with all normal colors, images and layouts.So if Drupal is working then why not Open Atrium's graphics and layouts are displayed. What could be wrong really? Thanks

Comment: "What could be wrong really?" - myriad of things, really. Impossible to guess, too many possibilities.

Comment: Check your Drupal log and Apache error log for suspicious messages. Probably your problems is related to the CSS compressed files that Drupal generates when CSS compression is enabled. If disabling this comression you can see the pages styled then probably the problem is the generated files aren't writted.

Comment: @tunic I cannot find any files in sites\default\files folders. There are folders but there are no files inside!

Comment: Probably permissions on your temp directory and/or files directory.

Comment: One of your first steps in debugging should be to log in and go to the status report page. If it is a file permissions problem it will tell you there.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a permissions issue on your temp and possibly also files directory. Go to `admin/config/media/file-system` and make sure that the directory set as your temporary directory exists, is writeable to the webserver, and is specified from your server's root directory. Also make sure `sites/default/files` and/or `sites/[yoursite]/files` (if using a multisite) exists and is writeable to the webserver.

Comment: Please check my the latest warning messages as edited in my question.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect those errors.